# JSON encoded array, how to use in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Ok I've got this code in a file test.php:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "DB");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "failed to connect:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$grab = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM DB");
$cars = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grab)){
    array_push($cars, array("id" => $row["Id"], "name" => $row["Name"], "color" => $row["Color"];
}
echo json.encode($cars);
```

And I've got the jQuery code on my HTML page:

```
$.get("test.php", function($cars){
    $("itemNameLink1").html($cars.name);
    console.log($cars.name);
});
```

My next question is how do I access the data in my json_encoded array and use it in my jQuery on the HTML page. Right now I only get back undefined in console log. It was only my first try so wasn't disheartened by it. But any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: `json.encode`? that a typo?, any way, you need to loop the response, since this is most likely to have many rows

Comment: yeah sorry, I've done that twice now.

Comment: apparently `cars` is an array ? you are accessing `name`, which is probably a property of an individual car, not of the array.

Comment: well its an array of associative arrays.

Comment: @user3879560 What happens if you do `console.log($cars);`?

Comment: I suppose I want to reference the name of the car. The output of the php is something like this [{"name":"name1, "color etc},{"name":"name2", "color etc},{"name":"name3", "color etc}]. I'm not exactly sure how JSON encodes the arrays. all I want to know is, is there a way to reference them using jquery.

Comment: @user3879560: `I want to reference the name of the car` which car? you have a whole array of them

Comment: thanks for the help, but I'm gonna try and reference all of them, I've got an idea, I'm going to ask another question to see what people think.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you try to access `name` property of `$cars` array instead of `name` property of each car. You should to iterate through your array first:

```js
for(var car in $cars){
    console.log(car.name);
}
```

or

```js
$cars.forEach(function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

if you maintain only modern browsers. Or use `$.each` method as @StartCoding mentioned.

**AND**, again as @StartCoding mentioned use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get` or `$.parseJSON($cars)` if you've got a string in you response (it possible if your server returned wrong MIME-type [*text/plain* for example instead *application/json*]).

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get("test.php", function($cars){
 $.each($.parseJSON($cars), function(i, val){
$("itemNameLink1").html(val.name);
console.log(val.name);
});
});
```

Comment: doesn't work, console log just gives a list of names. no change to itemNameLink1, it's ok, it'll take a bit to get my head round this.